# SQL Server : compare columns in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server table with following columns:

- Clientnum
- Location
- Benefits
- SomeOtherFields

And I need to be able to compare all the rows for a particular client and see which columns were changes/modified.

My usual approach is to concatenate all the columns for each row of the client and compare the concatenated string.

But somehow I know there could be a better approach (and besides my approach doesn't really tell me which columns were changes and before/after values).

Any suggestions would be helpful. Please note that I can not make any DBA level changes like track changes etc. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look up `LEAD` and `LAG` functions. Also, do you have a primary key column on this table?

Comment: You're asking us how to tell which rows are before and which are after?   How are we supposed to know if you don't?

Comment: @TabAlleman:  I have a time stamp which I can use to get the most recent record for a client but I also need to be able to check it against the second most recent and see which columns were changed.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: Yes, I have a composite primary key,

Comment: Which version of SQL Server (you have two tags on your question.)  2012 supports LEAD and LAG.  2008 does not and would require a different (less elegant) solution.

Comment: @DeadZone: SQL 2012 (sorry for missing that out)

Answer (score 0):

An option to accomplish this is to create a history table, and create Insert, Update, and delete triggers.  Then you can query the history table to find all the details that you needed.

sample code:

```js
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[uTests] 
   ON  [dbo].[Tests] 
   AFTER DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
 
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Log updated/delete record
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tests_TransHistory]
  (ID
 
  ,[Test_Name]
 
  ,[TestDate]
 
  ,[UpdateDate]
  ,[UpdateUser]
 
 SELECT 
  ID
 
  ,[Test_Name]
 
  ,[TestDate]
 
  ,[UpdateDate]
  ,[UpdateUser]
  
 FROM DELETED;
 
 --Update the time stamps.
 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
 BEGIN
  UPDATE dbo.Tests_TransHistory
  SET UpdateDate = getdate(), UpdateUser = current_user
  WHERE TransID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
  UPDATE a
  SET a.UpdateDate = getdate(), a.UpdateUser = current_user
  FROM dbo.Tests a, INSERTED b
  WHERE a.ID = b.ID
 END

END
​
```

Comment: I believe that the OP is looking for a solution that will work on data that already exists in the table.  A logging solution would only work on changes made moving forward.  Perhaps the OP can clarify?

Comment: @DeadZone: It's only for rows that will be added going forward. But is there a way I can avoid the new table creations... We looked into this approach and wanted to create minimum objects in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't enable Query Notifications and use the [SqlDependancy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

You could add a column of type `ROWVERSION` to your table. Every time a row is updated, SQL Server updates a column of type `ROWVERSION` with a new unique `varbinary(8)` value.  Using this you can check if the `ROWVERSION` column changed at all and skip over those rows.  If they don't match, then you can check the fields in only those rows individually.

Another option would be to use the HASHBYTES function to detect changes.  If your client pulls down a view... you could add hashed values in your select.  Something like:

```
select *,
  HASHBYTES ('MD5', Clientnum) ClientnumHash,
  HASHBYTES ('MD5', Location) LocationHash,
  HASHBYTES ('MD5', Benifits) BenifitsHash,
  HASHBYTES ('MD5', SomeOtherFields) SomeOtherFieldsHash
 from Table
```

Then you can just compare the results of the hash functions, comparing varbinary(16) (max lenght of the MD5 method) instead of the entire strings of the columns.